# React Native - Do a search bar for ios or android

Tags: reactjs, native

I've been searching for a search bar component for ios and android so i can use in my app. So far I have found none, that's why I want to make one. How can I show a view when I click a button? So when they click the search icon, the search bar appears. Or any way to do a search bar? 
Thank you!

Comment: so far what you have tried

Comment: I've searched a good react component that i can take advantage of but found ios ones only and tried this tutorial 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_4Ll0-5abc' but is really outdated and couldn't get it to work. @VishweshJainkuniya

Answer (score 4):

There are many tutorials available on **Internet**`

Some of them

var SearchBar = require('react-native-search-bar');

and

```
<SearchBar
ref='searchBar'
placeholder='Search'
onChangeText={...}
onSearchButtonPress={...}
onCancelButtonPress={...}
/>
```

Some useful links

- https://github.com/umhan35/react-native-search-bar
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-search
- https://github.com/StevenIseki/react-native-search/tree/master/SearchBarExample
- https://www.briandouglas.me/2016/02/08/searching-data-in-react-native

[image]

[image]

Comment: These all works in iOS but no luck in android, all the instruction are for iOS. RNPM also doesn't works for these.

Answer (score 4):

[react-native-elements 1.0.0-beta5](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html) has a component for both iOS and Android searchbars. The current version SearchBar works with Android too but is without the Android style.

```
npm install --save react-native-elements@1.0.0-beta5

<SearchBar
   showLoading
   platform="android"
   placeholder='Search' />
```

Then it looks like this:
[image: Android]

Comment: it's not taking style so it is showing from top 0 of the view how do i change it's style and show it margin 40 so that my header view show properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm i react-native-element --save
//code here
state = {
 search: '',
};
updateSearch = search => {
  this.setState({search});
};
.... // some things here
<SearchBar
      onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
      value={search}
      lightTheme
      round
      showLoading
      placeholder="Search"
      icon={{type: 'font-awesome', name: 'search'}}
      cancelIcon={{type: 'font-awesome', name: 'cancelIcon'}}
      leftIconContainerStyle
      inputStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
      placeholderTextColor={'#g5g5g5'}
      platform="ios"
      cancelButtonTitle="Cancel"
      containerStyle={{
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderRadius: 100,
      }}
      cancelButtonProps={{
        color: 'red', //color of text: Cancel
      }}
    />
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering the question. But rather than just posting a block of code, can you give some explanation as to what it does (for example what the problem was you solved and how you solved it?) this will help us understand your answer better and learn from it.